# How to get your iOS app to run in the background for longer than 3 minutes?

Tags: ios, background-task

It seems like older versions of iOS allowed your app to run for 10 minutes in the background. Now it seems like iOS only allows your app to run for a maximum of 3 minutes. I haven't found any documentation mentioning when, or in which versions, this changed, or any estimates provided by Apple for how long your app can run in the background.

I need to be able to run in the background, because my app is connected to an external device via TCP. I already know about the hacks you can do with VOIP and playing silent audio (both will get your app rejected).

Is there anything I can do to get my app to keep running in the background longer than 3 minutes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We haven’t had the old 10 minute window for years so that is simply no longer applicable. That was reduced to 3 minutes in OS 7, and further reduced to 30 seconds in iOS 13. (There is a new concept of [background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks), for running tasks longer than 30 seconds, but the the OS will run these at its own discretion, e.g. at night, when the user is charging their device, so that’s not really applicable here).

The short answer to your question is that you cannot submit apps to the store that run in the background indefinitely unless it’s one of a very limited list of permitted background modes.

If you can go to the “Signing & Capabilities” tab of your target and add “Background Modes” and you can see the list of alternatives:

[image]

So, with the caveat that you cannot do precisely what you asked, here are a few observations:

1. The “External accessory communication” background mode (see [ExternalAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory)) seems promising, but that’s for bluetooth or wired connections only. So unless you can refactor/reengineer how your devices communicates, that is likely not a viable solution.
2. There’s an interesting question of whether just keeping the app running in the foreground might be helpful (e.g. judicious use of [`idleTimerDisabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623070-idletimerdisabled)). I know this solves a different problem (and should be used only where essential), but perhaps it’s option for you.
3. If your external device is Internet-enabled and you want it to inform the app of some event, perhaps you can have it communicate its intent to some web service that then triggers an APNS push notification that your device can receive.

Bottom line, you can’t do what you ask, but if you edit your question with more details about the nature of the device and what your iOS app wants to do with that device, we might be able to provide better counsel. But in answer to the general question “can I just keep app running perpetually in the background”, the answer is “no.”

Comment: Good, elaborate answer

Comment: Great answer, thank you @Rob. Running in the foreground won't work because we're trying to solve the case of locking the screen and putting the phone in your pocket. I attempted successive long-polling HTTP requests, but I haven't been able to get that to work and I'm not sure it would work anyway, so I'm not sure if I should continue down that route or not.